# Animate loaded subview

Tags: objective-c, ios

How would I make this code animate in the `SplashView` NIB instead of just making it appear (e.g. the `UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal` style)?  I am using a `UITabBarController` type project.

```
- (IBAction)showSplash:(id)sender {

// Hide toolbar
self.tabBarController.tabBar.hidden = YES;

// Splash
[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed: @"SplashView" owner: self options: nil];
[self.view addSubview: splashView];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bit hard to tell your context with this small bit of code. Basically, if you want to push a viewController modally, in your -(IBAction)showSplash method (you don't need to send the sender if you're not using it, BTW), I would use some code similar to this:

```
SplashViewController *svc = [[SplashViewController alloc] init]; (assuming nib is same name)
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
[self presentModalViewController:svc animated:YES];
[svc release];
```

Then in your SplashViewController you would have an IBAction that calls:

```
[self dismissModalViewController animated:YES];
```

You don't actually have to hide the tabBar when you are presenting a modalViewController. It won't be there. The idea of a modalViewController is that it blocks all user interaction with the app except for the modal view, until it is dealt with.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What do I need to do in my FirstViewController.h to reference the SplashViewController class?  Just include the .h?

Comment: Yes. In whatever view you want to use the SplashViewController, just #import the .h and then you can do what I suggested above. Usually, you would add it in the .m, unless you need to declare the SplashViewController in your .h for some reason.

Comment: Out of curiousity, why would I put it into the H as well?  Is it only when I want to declare types from the SplashViewController.h at class level?

Comment: If you wanted to make a SplashViewController ivar, or property, for example the .h would need to know about that class.